# UIScrollView events for scrolling that definitely occurred

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am working with a`UIScrollview`, and based on if the user scrolls left or right, I reconfigure the UI. The problem is that I need to verify that the user definitely crossed from one screen to another (something along `contentOffset`).

I've tried using this method:

```
  -(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

But this will fire if the user kind of moves the scrollview partially in one direction, but then doesn't complete the gesture.

I've also tried this method:

```
   -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

but mainly the same issue; the scrollview scrolls left and right, but on an iPhone, with a content with of 640 ( 320 * 2). I am trying to figure out if the scroll did cross over or not, from one location to the other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, what information/capability are you missing with `-scrollViewDidScroll`? It gets called any time the user pans the scroll view, and you can inspect `scrollView.contentOffset` to get the current position of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this :

I have a variable to maintain the x location of the contentOffset

```
 -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   currX = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x;
 }
```

And then in this event :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == currX ) {
      return;//This is what I needed, If I haven't panned to another view return
   }
 //Here I do my thing.
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "crossed from one screen to another" I assume you mean paging? If so, here's what you can do:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    int page = sender.contentOffset.x / width;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:page]; // in case you need it for updating a UIPageControl
}
```

Comment: well there is no PageControl perse, sorry for the word choices, in my case the scrollview scroll left and right, on an iPhone, with a content with of 640 ( 320 * 2). I am trying to figure out if the scroll did cross or not from one locattion to the other, because you can have cases where the user kind of drags the scrollview a bit, but then releases it and it doesn;t cross like a threshold that makes it move to the next screen.

Comment: Are you using paging on the scrollview? Because then this functionality comes built in for free.